# How to create flexible authentication mechanism in Java web application

Tags: java, authentication, java-security

I have a need to add authentication to a web application.  There are several articles, tutorials, and other posts on this topic I've looked at including the following:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html#RunAc

https://dzone.com/articles/java-web-application-security

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bncck/index.html

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/07/22/servlet-authentication

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html

There's also this but it only authenticates for one page and not across an entire web application and is admittedly not really a working solution for production applications:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/servlet/java-servlet-authentication-example/

All of the methods I'm finding use either a properties file defined in the web server (JBoss, Glassfish, Jetty, etc.) or a sql query defined in the web server configuration.

Is there a way to implement authentication in a Java web app such that it is configurable within the web application (e.g. create a class that is called when an attempt is made to access a servelt)?

I would like to be able to implement authentication logic that can be easily modified.  For example, I would like to first implement a hard coded authentication (if uid=="scott" && pwd="tiger") and then change the implementation to use a database lookup of uid/pwd and then change the implementation to use Oauth2 or other SSO method).

Comment: Well you still will have to persist some part of a authentication credentials.  Take a look at shiro - https://shiro.apache.org/

Comment: Yup, I ended up going with Shiro.  If you post this as an answer all mark it as accepted.